# How can I have more languages in an android app?

Tags: android

I want to set in my android app more languages : english, french, german,italian. That's mean that when I choose one of them in the app all the text from textviews, button..will appear in that language. How can I do that? Should I save the words from all app in a local SQlite database ? Can you provide me some examples? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the techniques you need are covered in the [Localization guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the res/values/strings.xml in your ressource folder.
After that you can create multiple folders, e.g. "values-en" for the english strings.xml
or values-fr/strings.xml for french. Check [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html).